# Finding correct jar file to work with scala example

Tags: java, scala, lift-json

I am trying to do an example [here](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/simple-scala-lift-json-example-lift-framework) and (I believe) I am running into issues because my version of Lift is wrong. My specific error is: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.thoughtworks.paranamer.Paranamer` How do I know which version of Lift I should be using in this case? I downloaded my version from [here](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/scala-tools/net/liftweb/lift-json_2.11/2.6.2/lift-json_2.11-2.6.2.jar)

My code (copied directly from the site linked above):

```
import net.liftweb.json._
import net.liftweb.json.DefaultFormats

object SarahEmailPluginConfigTest {

implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
case class Mailserver(url: String, username: String, password: String)

val json = parse(
"""
{ 
  "url": "imap.yahoo.com",
  "username": "myusername",
  "password": "mypassword"
}
"""
)

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val m = json.extract[Mailserver]
    println(m.url)
    println(m.username)
    println(m.password)
  }

}
```

Comment: do you use any build tool?

Comment: No. I am extremely new to scala, and so far I havent needed them

Comment: Yeah, I think you need one, read the way to work with SBT, it extremely easy to work.

Answer (score -1):

Works for me using version lift-json_2.10 3.0-M1

Can be downloaded [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.liftweb/lift-json_2.10/3.0-M1).

**EDIT**

You can use json4s, which usually works exactly the same as lift.

Using these libraries the following works for me:

```
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json4s/json4s-native_2.11/3.2.11
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json4s/json4s-ext_2.11/3.2.11
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json4s/json4s-core_2.11/3.2.11
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json4s/json4s-ast_2.11/3.2.11

import org.json4s.DefaultFormats
import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods._

object SarahEmailPluginConfigTest {

  implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
  case class Mailserver(url: String, username: String, password: String)

  val json = parse(
    """
      {
        "url": "imap.yahoo.com",
        "username": "myusername",
        "password": "mypassword"
      }
      """
  )

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val m = json.extract[Mailserver]
    println(m.url)
    println(m.username)
    println(m.password)
  }

}
```

Comment: Did not work for me using that JAR. What version of scala are you running?

Comment: Sorry, downloaded that jar, but still imported another library. Updated my post accordingly. Shouldn't be a problem to just use those, they work the same.

Comment: No it did not. I downloaded the 4 JARS you linked above, placed them in the folder lib and when I ran the code I got `object json4s is not a member of package org`

Comment: Did you add the jars to the build path?

Comment: It's probably best if you read up on sbt, as Omid suggested, and add it as a dependency, that way you won't miss any dependencies of your libraries.